# Input value with a min and max number

Tags: javascript, html

Below is an input number form and with JavaScript, I have added some line of codes with the minimum number that can be written is 1 and the maximum number to be written would be 50. 
And when someone would try to type any number less than 1 and greater than 50 it would automatically replace it with number 1 or 50 but I'm not having success achieving this and I need your help.

```js
    document.getElementById('info1').addEventListener("input", function () {
    let num = +this.value, max = 50, min = 1;
    if (num > max || num < min) {
        return false;
      }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="info1" size="4">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's already a HTML attribute pair for this exact purpose - `min` and `max`:

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="50">
```

If you also want this to occur when a user enters a number outside of the range:

```js
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", function() {
  let v = parseInt(this.value);
  if (v < 1) this.value = 1;
  if (v > 50) this.value = 50;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="50" id="inp">
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking to use this but I can type in a minus number like -1 and wouldn't be the minimum then

Comment: OK @Behar, fixed - try typing a number then pressing enter/return.

Comment: It still stays the same number when I type like -1, 0, etc so I am able to type negative numbers and less than 1 and greater than 50?

Comment: See my second snippet @Behar.

Comment: Your code didn't have JS code so that's why and now with JS tried and it works, thank you :)
And a question about a negative number like -1, in your code I don't see any if statement for negative numbers like if I type -1 it automatically replaces to 1, so I think "  if (v < 1) this.value = 1;
  if (v > 50) this.value = 50;"
They compare for negative value right ?

Comment: see my previous comment if you can answer to that question of negative number please, thanks :)

Comment: Yes @Behar - the `< 1` checks if it's less than the lowest value 1, and updates it if it is. It also works for 0.

Answer (score 6):

```
function imposeMinMax(el){
  if(el.value != ""){
    if(parseInt(el.value) < parseInt(el.min)){
      el.value = el.min;
    }
    if(parseInt(el.value) > parseInt(el.max)){
      el.value = el.max;
    }
  }
}

<input type=number min=1 max=50 onkeyup=imposeMinMax(this)>
```

Comment: Best answer i've found after 30 min on Google :)