# Keep min value of number input with jQuery when the user enter number

Tags: html, jquery

I have an input tag, which the type is number. It has just **`min`** value "1" and no max value.

```
<div id="average_wrap" class="average_wrap">
  <input id="average" class="average" type="number" min="1">
</div>
```

If I enter -5 or 0, which is less than **`min`** value of the input tag, the input didn't prevent this. I want to prevent the input less than **`min`** value and put a warning for those cases, or something like that.

What is the easy way to accomplish this?

This is similar question: [Input value with a min and max number.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719160/input-value-with-a-min-and-max-number) But it does not prevent the input and it just changes the **`min`** value to 1. Also, it's built with javascript (I want **jQuery**) and there is no way to pop a **warning**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input value with a min and max number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719160/input-value-with-a-min-and-max-number)

Comment: @0stone0, it's similar. But it does not prevent the input and it changes the `min` value to 1. Also, it's built with javascript (I want jQuery) and there is no way to pop an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do it like this.

```
jQuery("#average").on('input', function(){
    let error_tag = jQuery(".error_tag");
    error_tag.text("");
    if (jQuery(this).val() < 1) {
        jQuery(this).val("");
        error_tag.text("Please enter a valid number. It should be greater than 0.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already resolved this, but this is exactly what I was looking for.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery function, please try to do like this.

```
$(document).on('input', '#average', function() {
    if( $(this).val() < 1) {
      $(this).val(1)
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to prevent input if it's less than `min` value? and pop an **alert** for that?

Comment: If the customer input 0, the input value will be 1 according to this code. And if the customer click '-', it will also fill 1 in the input element. You can add some code for handling the some use cases more perfectly.

Comment: If you want to create a pop up, you can add the code like this. ```$(document).on('input', '#average', function() {
    if( $(this).val() < 1) { alert ("please input more than 1")
      $(this).val("")
    } 
}); ```

Comment: What if we want to put a warning underneath the input element instead of an alert? Is there an easy way?

Comment: You can use the this example for it.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-error-without-alert-box-using-javascript/

Comment: Do you have an example with jQuery instead of javascript?

Comment: ```function errorMessage() {
       var error = $("#error");
        if (isNaN($("number").val()))
        {
             
            // Changing content and color of content
            error.text("Please enter a valid number");
            error.css("color", "red")
        } else {
            error.text("")
        }
    }```

Comment: ```jQuery("#average").on('input', function(){
    let error_tag = jQuery(".error_tag");
    error_tag.text("");
    if (jQuery(this).val() < 1) {
        jQuery(this).val("");
        error_tag.text("Please enter a valid number. It should be greater than 0.");
    }
}```

Comment: Can you please update your answer instead of comment?